# Safari display flex not working when elements are 25%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari, flexbox

We have an issue on iPads and Mac thats we really annoying.

We are using bootstrap, and have created 9 elements in a .row with .col-xs-12.col-sm-5.col-md-3 classes.

On the .row we have applied a .flex-start class with the following css:

```
.flex-start {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

In safari the first flex row only contains 3 items.

Sample [here](http://codepen.io/rasmuseeg/pen/EPqOJx) and screenshot [here](http://screencast.com/t/Oj5xk9MdZop). you must open in safari on Mac or iPad

Setting the width of col-md-3 to 24.9% fixes this, but we dont want that hack.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and know of a fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. There is a problem with the pseudo :after and :before elements which comes with the row class.

I think omittig the row class is not the best solution. In my case i could fix it in safari with this css:

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
    display: none;
}
```

You might also have a look at this post:

[Flexbox Safari bug (flex-wrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-safari-bug-flex-wrap)

Comment: Lifesaver! This saved me hours of work! Please remember to upvote the question as well.

Answer (score -2):

Simply Add "clearfix" class to row and add "float: left;" property to all columns inside the row.

This will work fine in Safari.