# Same height for Bootstrap 3 grid columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, flexbox

## What I have

I have some Bootstrap 3 Grid columns with different heights:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">Item 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Item 2 <br/> additional line
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Item 3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">Item 4 - This should be on a separate line</div>
</div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Bootstrap only style]

## What I want

I want to add an additional class (e.g. `.row-aligned`) to `.row` to achieve that all abreast "cols" have the same height.

Which should look like this:

[image: Cols with .row-aligned class]

## My attempt

Because I don't need to support old browsers I can use flexbox.
My attempt is quiet easy and works in all browsers but not in Safari (version 9.1, Mac OSX 10.10):

```
.aligned-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

*[I prepared a Demo here.](http://codepen.io/TheSchecke/pen/qZeGMO)*

### Safari Bug

As I said, Safari cannot handle this flexbox style and the result looks like this:

[image]

(I found out that adding `margin-left: -1px` seems to fix the issue, but it is not a good solution, because it will move everything 1 pixel left which can hide borders or something else.)

## My question

Do you have any idea how I can fix this bug in Safari? Or do I use flexbox wrong? Or is there a better solution without using flexbox?

Comment: Did you see this question and all of the various answers?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: Yes I did see that question, but no flexbox solution there worked in Safari and the other solutions weren't good either. And I also don't want to fix this with Javascript. I posted this separate question because I am more interested in understanding why flexbox doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-safari-bug-flex-wrap

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solution is to "remove" the `display: table` which is set to `.row::before`:

```
.aligned-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    &::before {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/TheSchecke/pen/ezOgGN)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class **display-flex** to **row** as follows:

```html
<div class="row display-flex">
```

And then add this CSS code.

```css
.row.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

:)
.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```