# Bootstrap 3 grid breaks on first line in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a shop page with rows of products. In chrome it appears fine, like this:

```
 __   __   __   __
|  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | |  |
 ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾ 
 __   __   __   __
|  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | |  |
 ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾
```

But in Safari the first line only has 3 elements:

```
 __   __   __ 
|  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  |
 ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾ 
 __   __   __   __
|  | |  | |  | |  |
|  | |  | |  | |  |
 ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾   ‾‾
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    ...
      <div class="container">
        ...
          <ul class="row">
            <li>
              ...
            </li>
          </ul>
        ...
      </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given a class of `col-md-3` to each product item. This means a width of `25%`. But you are also giving it some padding, which will increase its width to more than 25% causing the last element to go into next line.

Also, the entire structure seems to be poorly coded. Anyway, here is a quick solution to your problem. Add this to CSS at the end.

```
.products .product { width: 24%; }
```

Also, i see you have this code in your files. This seems to be a cause to me as well.

```
.products .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1), .products .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) { clear: none; }
```

Comment: In the inspector I see that the width of each product is 285px and the container/row are 1140px. So that should add up to 4 products in a row - as in the other ones. Adding `width:24%` looks a bit too hacky... I also tried to remove the line you suggested but I don't see a difference.

Comment: But removing the line right next to it did solve the problem! Thanks

Comment: Too hacky, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-wraps-last-column-of-the-first-row-in-safari

Answer (score 5):

Just use this snippet in your css (sass/less) file.

```
.row:before, .row:after{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Should be working afterwards.

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9282#issuecomment-413421690

Answer (score 0):

This might be you gave

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;

In the col-md-3. Remove it and it will work.