# bootstraps grid row as flexbox is displayed different on iPads

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, flexbox, mobile-safari

I use Bootstrap 3 in my webproject. Therefore in the grid all cols per row get the same height I found the solution to set them as `display: flex`with `flex-wrap: wrap;`

My HTML structure is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now all browsers displayes coorectly two rows with two columns and the last row has only a single column.

Now the problem is, that my iPads display at first a row with one single item and the other to rows has two items. Has anybody an idea what could be the reason?

You‘ll find the html+css here: http://portaltechnik.gerrit-lober.de

Thanks!

Thats right:
[image: Displayed correct on desktop browsers]

Thats wrong:
[image: Displayed WRONG on iPad]

Comment: add `float:none` to column

Comment: Combine Bootstrap 3 and Flexbox can cause a lot of issues since Bootstrap 3 use `float`...use Bootstrap 4 instead, which is based on Flexbox

Comment: We can't debug your images. Provide a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue you encounter.

Comment: I use an existing theme. So there is bootstrap 3 fixed. Can I attache the URL?.http://portaltechnik.gerrit-lober.de/startseite.html

Comment: Found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-safari-bug-flex-wrap