# Issues with Flex/Flex-Flow in Desktop vs Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

Running into some strange behavior after testing my responsive website on mobile and hoping I can get some insight here into what is going on. Basically, I have a single bootstrap row that contains 23 images. On my iPhone resolution (375 x 667), I am seeing different results with how the row is displayed compared to a desktop browser set to that resolution.

My goal is to have the images display side-by-side in pairs until the last line, which will have a centered image. In addition to the standard bootstrap row class, I have also added a class called flex that uses the following css:

```
.flex { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

The HTML is similar to this:

```
<div class="row flex">
    <div class="customColumn">
        <img src="some-image" class="img-responsive some-image-class" alt="some alt"/>
    </div>
    <div class="customColumn">
        <img src="some-image" class="img-responsive some-image-class" alt="some alt"/>
    </div>
    <div class="customColumn">
        <img src="some-image" class="img-responsive some-image-class" alt="some alt"/>
    </div>
    <div class="customColumn">
        <img src="some-image" class="img-responsive some-image-class" alt="some alt"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

On desktop, no matter how small I make the screen, the images display as expected. For some reason on mobile, the first image in the group is the one that is displayed by itself, and the images after that are displayed in pairs.

Why would this display behavior be opposite for desktop versus mobile?

CodePen showing expected behavior: codepen.io/anon/pen/jZWGNj . The problem is that this behaves completely opposite on mobile (iPhone, Android, iPad).

Edit: I just want to clarify that 'custom columns' in this case are just the canned bootstrap columns as far as the width values are concerned.

Comment: Anyone? It is like the effect of wrap-reverse is being used for mobile display, even though the CSS is wrap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B I am not sure I understand, I seem to have met 9/10 of the requirements/suggestions in that link. Regardless, I have a code pen showing the correct behavior: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZWGNj . On desktop, the last row is single and centered. On mobile, the first row is single and centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles across this issue again, the answer can be found in this thread: [Flexbox Safari bug (flex-wrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-safari-bug-flex-wrap)

Turns out this issue was not a mobile display issue, it was an iOS issue and how :before and :after is handled. The fix in the above thread worked for me.