# Bootstrap columns not working on ios devices as they should

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, semantic-ui

I have made a card using bootstrap. The columns work fine in all the devices. But they completely change in any ios devices. Screenshot attached.

http://projecttesting.tk/sfl/test.html 
is my card on test server.

[image: Mobile Version]
[image: Desktop Version]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhjm8ztn/

```
<section class="card__list row">
    <div class="card__box col-md-12 col-sm-12">

      <div class="card">

        <div class="card__content">
            <div></div>
            <div class="ribbon"><span>Sponsored</span></div>
          <div class="row card__bottom2">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-8 contest">
                        <img src="index.png" width="25px" height="25px"> <span class="card__title">MyTeam11</span>
                        <div class="date2">
                          <span class="time"> (2 Minutes Ago) </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>    



                <div class="col-3 col-sm-4 col-md-2 center3 card__price">
                        <span class="card__title">66%</span>
                  <div class="date">
                    Overlay
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3 col-sm-4 col-md-2 center3 card__price">
                        <span class="card__title">25%</span>
                        <div class="date">
                          Margin
                        </div>
                      </div>
          </div>

        <div class="row card__bottom">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 left options">
              <span class="date weight">
                1.6 Million Monster 
                </span>
                <div class="date2">
                  43.6 % Overlay
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 center card__price">
                    <span class="date weight"> ₹ 1600000</span>
              <div class="date2">
                Prizepool
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 right left2 card__price">
                    <span class="date weight"> 55555</span>
             <div class="date2">
              Max Entries
            </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 left center2 card__price">
                    <span class="date weight"> ₹ 35</span>
              <div class="date2">
               Entry Fee
             </div>
              </div>

             <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 center left2 card__price">
              <progress id="pb0" value="620" max="1760"></progress>
              <div class="date2">
                620/1760 Joined
              </div>
             </div>


             <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 center2 right card__price">

              <div class="date2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btncs btn-primary">Join Now</button>
              </div>
             </div>




       </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    </div>






    </section>
```

I have tried to change the display property but it was not helpful.

Comment: With using flexbox on .card__bottom, iOS is treating the :before psuedo as a flex element which is causing the break in the layout. You may find the answer on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250282/flexbox-wraps-last-column-of-the-first-row-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

add below code at the end of your css code i hope this should work in ios all sizes

```
@media(min-width:320px) and (max-width:1024px){
.left2 {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.card__price {
    text-align: right !important;
}

.left2 {
    text-align: left !important;
}
}
```

Comment: similarly you can change expected alignment for some other device sizes

Comment: no it didn't work. So i am still confused that i've just used simple columns from bootstrap, why is it giving problems in ios devices. As in, chech the ss, the main area of the card, the first column shifted to right, the right one shifted below to left, and so on. this happens only on iphones